# The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided error in Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to docker desktop cluster. Application has a database connection to Postgresql. I am not getting an error on localhost (working with application-test.yml) but getting error in application pod in k8s. **The error is: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.** My db username:postgres and password:123456

base64 format located in credential.yml file.

How can I solve this error ?

application.yml;

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:5432/${DB_NAME}
    username: {POSTGRES_USER}
    password: {POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    show-sql: true
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/triangel
    username: postgres
    password: 123456
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    show-sql: true
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

deployment.yml;

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: triangel
  labels:
    name: triangel
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: triangel
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: triangel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: triangel
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: triangel
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: triangel
          image: localhost:5000/triangel
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:   # Setting Enviornmental Variables
            - name: DB_HOST   # Setting Database host address from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-conf  # name of configMap
                  key: host
            - name: DB_NAME  # Setting Database name from configMap
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-conf
                  key: name
            - name: POSTGRES_USER  # Setting Database username from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials # Secret Name
                  key: postgres_user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD # Setting Database password from Secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: postgres_password
```

postgres-configmap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-conf
data:
  host: postgres
  name: triangel
```

postgres credentials.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-credentials
data:
  postgres_user: cG9zdGdyZXM=
  postgres_password: MTIzNDU2
```

postgres-deployment.yml

```
# Define a 'Service' To Expose postgres to Other Services
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None

---
# Define a 'Persistent Voulume Claim'(PVC) for Postgress Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tier: database

spec:
  selector: # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' selectors
        app: postgres
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: postgres_user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: postgres_password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB # Setting Database Name from a 'ConfigMap'
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-conf
                  key: name

          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-persistance-storage
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-persistance-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

My pod's error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:633) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at com.proto.triangel.TriangelApplication.main(TriangelApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[triangel.jar:na]

2021-09-07 08:30:34.575  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
2021-09-07 08:30:34.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-09-07 08:30:34.593  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-07 08:30:34.609 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at com.proto.triangel.TriangelApplication.main(TriangelApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[triangel.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[triangel.jar:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:318) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:633) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

[image: Postgres pod log]

[image: Application pod log]

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: k8s Version:  1.21 @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: Did you see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824565/psqlexception-the-server-requested-password-based-authentication-but-no-passwo)?

Comment: I read it but it is not the same @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: Please paste your logs from your application pod and your server.

Comment: As I mentioned at my question. The error is: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided. @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: Great, we know what the problem is, but we have no idea why. I am asking for these logs to see what happened before this error occurred. This error is the result of something else and we need to check it out.

Comment: I am using liquibase for database migration. Error is; org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided. @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: Detailed Error: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.

Comment: Please read my comments once again. I need your pod logs from your application pod and your server. We know the password was not provided, but we don't know why. Maybe there is no connection between the base and the application, maybe the connection is broken somewhere, maybe the application does not give credentials at all, because there is a problem with it? I won't be able to help you, with no logs.

Comment: my pod log: https://easyupload.io/3287zf @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: Don't use external platform to store logs. Please edit your question and add your logs as the formatted text.

Comment: I added @MikołajGłodziak

Comment: To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. - Did you try it? You have attached logs only from the one pod. You should add both, as I have mentioned before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236845/discussion-between-bertug-and-mikolaj-glodziak).